# Text not displaying on google talk on Windows 7 (Ubuntu Wine)

Tags: ubuntu, google-talk

is there any solutions to display the text on google talk... Please help

P.S I installed google talk on wine in ubuntu oerating system.

many thanks ahead the time..

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the Google Talk for Windows app to work on Wine I would abandon those efforts because **any day now the Google Talk for Windows app will stop working completely for everyone so that google can push everyone to use hangouts**.  If you have hangouts enabled in your environment getting the chrome hangouts app working in ubuntu would serve you better.  I would post the link but don't have enough reputation points to add a third link.  Google google-hangouts-linux-opensuse-arch-ubuntu for the relevant article.

### Here is the official google notice link and text.

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/10/notification-re-google-talk-app-for.html

Notification re: Google Talk app for Windows replacement

Posted: 10/30/2014
Late last year, we announced that the Google Talk app for Windows was being retired. Soon, people using the Google Talk client for Windows will start seeing the following notification within the application:

Google Talk app for Windows is no longer supported. It is being replaced by the new Hangouts Chrome app. Install the Hangouts app from http://goo.gl/yglfk6. Please note, the Hangouts chat service must be enabled in the Admin console.

The Google Talk app for Windows will continue to work for approximately two months before being turned off completely. We will post a follow up notification within the application prior to the shut down.